# Best way to create restful

Tags: wcf, rest, complextype

Best way to create C# restful (webAPI or wcf) which can get complex object and return another complex object in GET method?

my request:

```
data: {
"Code":value,//Numerical Value
"vCode":value,//String Value
"arr":[{"bCode": value},{"bCode": value},...]
}
```

and my response:

```
data: {
"Code"://value,"vCode":    //value,
"Arr":[{"doc":{"tCode": 1,"cCode":1,"Type": 1,"Value": value},....], "FA":value,
"VN":value}
```

Comment: tanx for edit my post, Bob :))

Comment: Please help me in this case!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This following reference may be useful for Creating and Implementing WCF REST Service REST services

http://www.compilemode.com/2015/10/creating-wcf-rest-service-step-by-step.html

Comment: While that link might be a resource you can use to solve the issue, contents on other websites may change over time - so it's better to provide the information in the answer itself, and link to the website as a reference.